# Avoiding SSH timeouts on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, ssh

Every time I connect to a server with ssh, the connection is reset after a few minutes if there is no input. However, I want to remove these timeouts as to keep the connection alive for as long as possible.

By looking on different forums, I saw it was possible to modify the ServerAliveInterval option in the /etc/ssh_config file. However, there doesn't seem to be this option in my file. Where could it be?

I'm running OpenSSH_5.2p1 on Snow Leopard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Server Alive interval simply sends a null packet to the server at a set time to keep the connection alive, you should just be able to add some thing like into your config file: `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
 ServerAliveInterval 60
```

The second line must be indented with at least one space.
`*` will match any host; if you wanted you could restrict this to particular destinations like *somedomain.com.

Check out http://kehlet.cx/articles/129.html

Comment: ok but where can I find this option. In which file?

Comment: Just create a ~/.ssh/config file with something like the following (* will match any host, if you wanted you could restrict this to particular destinations like *kehlet.cx):  Check out http://www.kehlet.cx/articles/129.html

Comment: You should also be sure to indent the ServerAlive line with at least one space.

Comment: After I ssh to a remote host and then edit this config file, do I need quit the ssh connection and redo ssh again, or it will just works with existing ssh connection?

Comment: @StingJia - It sounds to me like you misunderstood the answer.  This is an ssh *client* setting, not an ssh *server* setting.  It is something you would need to configure on each SSH client.  Also, not that this answer naively assumes that you are running your ssh client on a UNIX-like operating system or sub-environment; if you are running something like PuTTY on Windows, you'll probably need to find and configure an analogous setting using different instructions.

Comment: link is dead   ....

Comment: On a Mac, open a terminal and from any directory type > nano ~/.ssh/config (don't type the >, that represents the command prompt)